# How to add color to transparent sections object in threejs

Tags: three.js

I'm new to threejs and trying to get the transparent sections of the object in this example to have some color https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20885327/project/examples/index.html. The object is a collection of 3 obj and corresponding mtl files. What is the approach for something like this?

I'm using this code to import the obj and mtl files using objmtlloader. Here the names in the array "files" correspond to the file names present in the obj directory containing obj models.

```
var variableName = {}
   ,files = ["L_Cortex","R_Cortex","Cerebellum"];
for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
  variableName[files[i]] =  new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
  variableName[files[i]].load( '../obj/'+files[i]+'.obj', '../obj/'+files[i]+'.mtl', function ( object ) {

      object.name = files[i];

      objects.push(object);

      scene.add( object );

  });   
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can affect the color of each group within the load callback.
Something like

```
object.traverse (function (mesh){
  if (mesh instanceof THREE.Mesh){

    // r, g, b are float between 0 and 1
    mesh.material.color.set(r, g, b);

    // you may want to adjust
    // mesh.material.transparent & mesh.material.opacity
  }
});
```

I see your objects use this material, for reference
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshLambertMaterial

Comment: Seems like the color only gets applied to where the png image is getting superimposed over the object. The transparent sections are still getting left out